# Why my Vuetify's Datepicker doesn't work?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm new to vuejs + vuetify. I am using a datepicker to filter a datatable. The filtering part is working, however, when I clear the field the table does not return to original form. I tested using the html's input-date and worked perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

This is the datepicker component:

```
    <template>
          <v-menu
                  ref="menu"
                  v-model="menu"
                  :close-on-content-click="false"
                  transition="scale-transition"
                  offset-y
                  max-width="290"
                  min-width="290"
          >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-text-field
                          clearable
                          dense
                          color="#15C98A"
                          outlined
                          v-model="computedDataFormatada"
                          label="data inicio"
                          append-icon="mdi-calendar-outline"
                          readonly
                          v-on="on"
                  ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-date-picker
                      v-model="date"
                      @input="dataEscolhida"
                      locale="pt"
                      color="#15C98A"
                      no-title
              ></v-date-picker>
          </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'DataPicker',
        props:['label'],
        data() {
            return {
                date: null,
                menu: false,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            computedDataFormatada () {
                return this.formataData(this.date)
            },
        },
        methods: {
            dataEscolhida() {
                    this.$emit('selecionado',this.computedDataFormatada);
                    this.menu = false;
            },
            formataData(date) {
                if (!date) return null;

                const [year, month, day] = date.split("-");
                return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

This is the way I'm filtering:

```
 <v-data-table
        fixed-header
        single-select
        item-key="id"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="customFilter"
        :items-per-page="5"
        class="elevation-1"
 ></v-data-table>


computed:{

 customFilter(){
                let startDate = this.dataInicioFiltro;
                let endDate = this.dataFimFiltro;
                return _.filter(this.grupos, (function (info) {
                    let date = info.data;
                    if ( (_.isNull(startDate) && _.isNull(endDate))||(_.isEmpty(startDate) && _.isEmpty(endDate)))
                        return true;
                    else if((!_.isEmpty(startDate) && _.isEmpty(endDate)))
                      return date ===startDate;
                    else if((_.isEmpty(startDate) && !_.isEmpty(endDate)))
                        return date ===endDate;
                    else
                    return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
                }))
            }
}
```

And this is how I'm using the component in the view:

```
  <data-filtro label="data  inicial" @selecionado="dataInicioFiltro=$event" />
```

I'm also using the lib  lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone, I finally solved it out! Just have to use the event **click:clear**